# Is this file compiled twice?

Tags: c++, compilation

Suppose `#include <something.h>` is contained in A.cpp and B.cpp

And If I run some function "A"  in A.cpp and  function "B" in B.cpp in the main,

Is "something.h" compiled twice? or once?

Comment: The code in `something.h` is compiled twice in this instance, yes.  This sounds like an XY problem - do you have some larger issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong question. What is compiled is technically not a source file, but a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Read more several books on C++, and some [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site.

Read also more about the various [compilation phases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), which includes [preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

So, assuming your compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux, you would compile the `A.cpp` source file (also the headers used in it, so a translation unit) with

```
 g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c A.cpp -o A.o
```

where `-Wall` asks for almost all warnings, `-Wextra` asks for more of them, `-g` asks for debug info (in DWARF format on Linux), `-c` asks for only compilation, `-o A.o` asks the object file to be `A.o`

You could ask the compiler to show every included header with the `-H` option.

You could get the preprocessed form using

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -C -E A.cpp > A.ii
```

then  you can look with a pager (or an editor) into the generated `A.ii` file.

Of course preprocessing would include the preprocessed form of a header at the point it is `#include`-d

Answer (score -1):

Since it's an header, it's not "compiled".
It's included as part of your code.

And to avoid some awkward situation, you have to protect your header like this :

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H_
#define SOMETHING_H_

/* your code goes here */

#endif /* something.h */
```